# Magento 2 : Can't add product to cart

Tags: php, magento2

After migrating from Magento 1.5 to Magento 2.2.4, not able to add to cart, it shows "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now."

Below is my expection.log file from var/log directory

[2018-06-05 09:51:00] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table **'hyl-old.salesrule_customer_group'** doesn't exist, query was:

```
    SELECT
        `main_table`.*
    FROM
        `salesrule` AS `main_table`
    INNER JOIN `salesrule_website` AS `website`
    ON
        website.website_id IN('1') AND main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id
    INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids`
    ON
        main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = 0
    WHERE
        (
            from_date IS NULL OR from_date <= '2018-06-05'
        ) AND(
            to_date IS NULL OR to_date >= '2018-06-05'
        ) AND(`is_active` = '1') AND(`main_table`.`coupon_type` = '1') AND(
            (main_table.to_date IS NULL) OR(
                main_table.to_date >= '2018-06-05'
            )
        ) AND(`is_active` = '1')
    ORDER BY
        sort_order ASC

{
    "exception" : "[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): 
                   SQLSTATE[42S02] : Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
                   'hyl-old.salesrule_customer_group' doesn't exist, query was: 

    SELECT
        `main_table`.*
    FROM
        `salesrule` AS `main_table`
    INNER JOIN `salesrule_website` AS `website`
    ON
        website.website_id IN('1') AND main_table.rule_id = website.rule_id
    INNER JOIN `salesrule_customer_group` AS `customer_group_ids`
    ON
        main_table.rule_id = customer_group_ids.rule_id AND customer_group_ids.customer_group_id = 0
    WHERE
        (
            from_date IS NULL OR from_date <= '2018-06-05'
        ) AND(
            to_date IS NULL OR to_date >= '2018-06-05'
        ) AND(`is_active` = '1') AND(`main_table`.`coupon_type` = '1') AND(
            (main_table.to_date IS NULL) OR(
                main_table.to_date >= '2018-06-05'
            )
        ) AND(`is_active` = '1')
    ORDER BY
        sort_order ASC

    at /home/wirw5dhnfutp/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/D 
    b/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base 

    table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hyl-old.salesrule_customer_group' 
    doesn't exist at home/wirw5dhnfutp/public_html/demo/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"

} []
```

Comment: Hi It clearly shows that the table 'hyl-old.salesrule_customer_group' is not existing in your database.

Comment: i searched the entire Database in Magento 1 and Magento 2, salesrule_customer_group table was not present in both the Magento versions. How do i fix it ?